# Merging specific rows based on consecutive duplicate values in same column

Tags: python, r, dplyr

Using R or python, i have a data set I would like to know how I could merge consecutive rows with consecutive duplicate entries.

Example

### X ....Y

cat...Q

---

dog...U

---

cat...T

---

dog...P

---

cat*...Y

---

cat*...K

---

dog...P

The column X has some entries, I would like to merge any rows that have the entry "cat" two consecutive times in a row (i have highlighted them with a "*") so they would become one row with the entries in column Y to be (Y , K).

### X.....Y

cat...Q

---

dog...U

---

cat...T

---

dog...P

---

cat...Y,K

---

dog...T

pretty much merging any rows with duplicate entries on one condition, if the are consecutive.

Comment: what do you want to do if there are 3 in a row

Comment: How many times do you plan on changing the question?  Not fun for the people that have already submitted answers.

Comment: @d_kennetz i'd like to do the same thing.

Comment: @RichScriven sorry just wanted to clarify that what i'm merging are sentences or words not characters.

Comment: You should not change your question.

Comment: duly noted @www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `base R` method with `aggregate`.  Create a grouping column by comparing adjacent elements equality of 'X', use that in `aggregate` to group by and `paste` elements together.

```
aggregate(Y ~ X + grp, transform(dat, 
    grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, X[-1] != X[-length(X)]))), 
           FUN = paste, collapse= ",")[c('X', 'Y')]
#    X   Y
#1 cat   Q
#2 dog   U
#3 cat   T
#4 dog   P
#5 cat Y,K
#6 dog   P
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(X = c("cat", "dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat", 
 "dog"), Y = c("Q", "U", "T", "P", "Y", "K", "P")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

---

Or using `python`

```
dat['grp'] = (dat.X != dat.X.shift()).cumsum()
out = dat.groupby(['grp', 'X'])['Y'].apply(lambda x: \
           ",".join(x)).reset_index()[['X', 'Y']]
print(out)
#     X    Y
#0  cat    Q
#1  dog    U
#2  cat    T
#3  dog    P
#4  cat  Y,K
#5  dog    P
```

#### data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = pd.DataFrame({'X': ["cat", "dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "cat", 
        "dog"], "Y": ["Q", "U", "T", "P", "Y", "K", "P"]})
```

Comment: the dat part? and what if the list is not that short? my data set is like 7000 rows

Comment: @MariamIbrahim  It should work for `n` number of rows.